# Error encode HTML on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a message:**Başlık** and encode html: `Ba%C5%9Fl%C4%B1k%3A%20`. I pass this message from Firefox browser to apllication local mail. But, in local mail, it show incorrect: **Baslik**. I try to with Chrome browser, it show properly: **Başlık**. I'm sure encode html: `Ba%C5%9Fl%C4%B1k%3A%20` in Firefox and Chrome is the same. not change any character. Could you tell me why they are different?